# Failed installation of Gem package through Gemfile in Amazon Linux 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-linux-2

I am working on migration our Ruby on Rails application from AWS platform Amazon Linux 1 to Amazon Linux 2 Platform.

I created an Elastci Beanstalk using Amazon Platform: Ruby 2.6 and Amazon Linux 2, and selected Amazon sample application as the first deployed application.

After modifying the Gemfile and deploment scripts of our EB application, I deployed new application to above environment.

In Gemfile, ruby, resque and resque-scheduler included:

```
ruby '2.6.8'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.1'

gem 'resque', '~> 2.0.0'

gem 'resque-scheduler', '~> 4.4.0'

...
```

After deployment, I access the EC2 instance through SSH and check the ruby on rails version . I get below response:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-203 ~]$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [x86_64-linux]
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-203 ~]$ rake --version
rake, version 12.3.3
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-203 ~]$ rails --version
-bash: rails: command not found
```

It seems Rails is not installed properly in the platform.

In Amazon Linux2, why rails cannot be installed through Gemfile during deployment process?
In our project, there are many dependencies are expected to be installed through Gemfile. But like rails, I concern some of these dependencies may not be installed through Gemfile anymore.

Rails, resque and resque-scheduler are automatically installed through Gemfile when we deploy the application to platform Amazon Linux1, but it seems something different in Amazon Linux2.

Can we still use Gemfile for install dependencies in Amazon Linux 2?